# getting values of all ticked items in checkboxes

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Let us suppose that I have three checkboxes and each checkbox has certain items to be checked say Item 1 ,Item 2,Item 3 which has value 'a' ,'b','c'.So if we click on item1,item2 and mark them ,we get an array with values a and b .Now if we click item3,we would get c .Again if we go to another checkbox now and click on another item in another checkbox,we would get another array which holds the values for the items we marked in second checkbox .
I need to store all marked items in an array and display it .The problem is to get all the ticked items for all the different checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

will the following perhaps set you in the right direction?

```js
var checkboxValues = [];
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
 if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
  checkboxValues.push(checkboxes[i].value);
 }
}
console.log('checkboxValues', checkboxValues);
```